# Is the transaction fee paid directly to the miner, or does the miner have to win a block in order to receive it?

Tags: blockchain, mining

I have studied blockchain architecture, and I know that my transaction will be broadcast to all nodes, which means more than 1 miner will execute my transaction in different nodes. So do they have to win the block in order to receive my transaction fee, or can they(miners) get it directly after finishing their effort(execution of transaction) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Proof-of-Work, the miner is the node that makes/wins the block, and is the only one that gets the transaction fees and rewards of that block.

Comment: Plus uncle rewards